# How to add gdbus-codegen to PATH on Ubuntu?

Tags: xfce-panel

I am trying to install xfce4-panel (from a tarball) on Ubuntu 20.04, however, when I run

> ./configure

I get an error:

> configure: error: could not find gdbus-codegen in $PATH. You can run
> ./configure GDBUS_CODEGEN=/path/to/gdbus-codegen to define
> a custom location for it.

The error says gdbus-codegen is not PATH but I am not sure where gdbus-codegen is or how I can add it to the PATH. If it helps, I am installing xfce4 from here: https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel (Also, I am very new to Ubuntu, I'm not sure if gdbus-codegen is even installed)

Comment: `gdbus-codegen` is provided by the `libglib2.0-dev-bin` package... but before installing it please tell us **why** you are trying to install `xfce4-panel` *from a source tarball*?

Comment: What was wrong with official xfce4-panel 4.14 [deb-package from repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xfce4-panel)? You are running Ubuntu, not Gentoo.

Comment: Is it not recommended to install from source tarballs? Also, I did not know about the deb-package from the repository, I will try installing from there.